# Automatic Zoom account switch

Tags: command-line, scripts, zoom-meeting

**My OS:**
Linux Ubuntu 18.04

**The problem:**
I have two Zoom accounts - one is work-related, one is private. I have to re-log about 20 times a day. You can imagine my frustration.
I was hoping that Zoom would enable some easy account switch, but no.

**What I did:**
Google search with "Zoom shortcuts" hoping that perhaps there is a key combination for account switching. ..No luck there.

**What I need:**
I need an application that would consist of 3 tasks:

1. logging out - THIS IS WHAT I FIRST NEED HELP WITH - THE 2) AND 3) DO NOT HAVE TO BE ANSWERED HERE, THEY ARE JUST A GENERAL INFORMATION
2. choosing an account
3. logging in with choosen account

Because there is no way that I could ask anybody to write such a program for free, the only way would be to build it from scratch. Difficult to a non-programmer.
My "general scheme" what would I, as a script author, would have to choose:

*1. Programming language*

A big unknown, especially since so far I've been only capable of "writing" .sh scripts that were such basic as:

> #!/bin/sh -e
>
> TERMINAL COMMAND
>
> exit 0

Q: What is your suggestion?

*2. Way of logging out*

The zoom log out - also not easy, requires commanding the application to "find" the log out button and press it. Precisely speaking: we are talking about the "switch account" button.
This is the first thing that I would start from, thus I am not asking how to develop the program any further right now.

Q: Any helpful ideas are welcome - do you think you could share some materials that you think I should read in this area?

**Final words:**
please bare in mind my lack of coding skills while writing your answer.
Guidance appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Zoom to see if they would be interested in adding that on as a future feature?

Comment: 1 other reason of doing it is "learning through exercise". Contacting Zoom in that matter is certainly a good idea, but I also feel its an opportunity to learn a little more advanced coding. If only somebody could point me in the right direction..

Comment: Ok...  Well, willingness and motivation alone aren't enough to get what you need to be done.  From what I can tell, `zoom` doesn't seem to have a command-line interface that allows someone to switch accounts easily.  Without such an interface available to you, I can't see how anyone would achieve what you want through programming.  The `zoom` executable seems to be just a graphical-interface-based program.  So...I'm not sure how you plan to do what you want to do, without contacting Zoom for some technical assistance.  The "right direction" is contacting Zoom...

Comment: I guess you are correct. Still - thank you for trying to help.